# Are there any cards that can boost my gate deck

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I'm currently making a gate land-based deck. I was wondering if there are any cards that would be able to either duplicate or copy any of the lands. Also if there were any cards that could possibly change another lands typing to gate.

Comment: Have you run a search on any card search engines, such as [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx), [Magiccards.info](http://magiccards.info/), or [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/)? Currently your question shows no research effort into the options available, such as [cards which mention "copy ... land"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=re%3A%22copy*land%22). If not, those ought to be your first port of call, and it helps to indicate what you've found and where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: I have a deck builder app that lists all the cards and I have the start to the deck. I asked my question because I was just making sure I was missing any obvious peice that maybe I didn't see.

Answer (score 1):

**There are various ways to copy lands, but no cards can change a land's type to "Gate"**

Cards such as [Vesuva](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVesuva%5d) and [Thespian's Stage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThespian%27s%5d%2b%5bStage%5d) copy a land directly, which is the simplest way of doing it.

Other methods exist, but are hardly practical, such as turning a Gate land into a creature through cards like [Animate Land](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimate%20Land%5d), then copying that land creature with another card such as [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d).

Comment: Animate Land and Clone seem very practical to me.  Why you hating on Animate Land?  It has brought joy to rules hackers for years.